# State not updating when executing onChange function in React

Tags: reactjs

My React function is picking up the value the user enters into a text box, and the console.log shows the value changing, but the state itself doesn't seem to change.

I have an external .js file with a list of clients, that I then import into the state:

```
const clients = [
  {
    _id: 'client1',
    name: 'Robert Beaney',
    bench: 93,
    squat: 150,
    deadlift: 209,
    total: 0,
    totalPounds: 0,
    kgAway: 0,
    poundsAway: 0,
    weight: [70, 65, 63]
  },
  {
    _id: 'client2',
    name: 'Client Two',
    bench: 60,
    squat: 135,
    deadlift: 160,
    total: 0,
    totalPounds: 0,
    kgAway: 0,
    poundsAway: 0,
    weight: [60, 55, 50]
  }
];
```

Imported into the state like so:

```
state = {
 clients: getClients()
};
```

When the user types a new number into an input box, I want the number to change the state. My code is as follows:

```
    <div className="row">
      {this.state.clients.map(client => {
        return (
          <div className="client col-md-6" key={client._id}>
            <p>{client.name}</p>
            <div className="enter-totals">
              <input
                type="text"
                id="total-bench"
                defaultValue={client.bench}
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
              />
```

And the function is:

```
handleChange(e) {
 let newBench = e.target.value;
 console.log(newBench);
 this.setState({ bench: newBench });
}
```

But nothing happens to the rendered {client.bench}

Any ideas?

Comment: You have two good answers below, but are you trying to change the `bench` state for a particular object or are you trying to update `state.bench`.  Valid answers below answer both those questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind to `defaultValue` - it's either that or `value`.

ideally, you want to actually change the client only that is affected so your handleChange should be:

```
handleChange(value, clientData){
  const { clients } = this.state;
  clients.some(client => { 
    if (client._id === clientData._id){
      client.bench = value;
      return true;
    }
  });
  this.setState({ clients }); 
}
```

then `onChange={e => this.handleChange(e.target.value, client)};`

and bind `value={client.value}` on the input.

Since you will have to change all the metrics, a more generic method would also accept 'prop' as argument, so you can `handleChange('deadlift', value, client)` and have a custom `handleWeightChange` where you push to the array.

And then, obviously, you want to make a `<ClientEdit client={client} onChange={} />` component etc and start making it modular.

I just get excited about gym stuff. Make all metrics arrays so you can track progress as well as regression and have the readings timestamped :D

Here's a working sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/545xy5q22k

Comment: Just a little correction, your if should be if (client._id === clientData._id) {

Comment: Yeah, cheers. Was just busy focusing more on what i'd want to track from a PT <--> client standpoint :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to add value to input element like value={this.state.bench}

Also initialise bench in state. Regarding binding a function directly in render isn’t recommended instead the binding should be done in constructor like

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
     this.state = {
         clients: getClients(),
          bench: ""
     };
     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

      <input
            type="text"
            id="total-bench"
            defaultValue={client.bench}
            value={this.state.bench}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
handleChange(id, value) {
  let clients = this.state.clients;
  let newClients = clients.map(client => {
    if(client._id === id) {
     client.bench = value;
    }
  })
  this.setState({ newClients })
}


return(
  <div className="row">
    {this.state.clients.map(client => {
       return (
         <div className="client col-md-6" key={client._id}>
           <p>{client.name}</p>
           <div className="enter-totals">
             <input
                type="text"
                id="total-bench"
                value={client.bench}
                onChange={e => this.handleChange(client._id, e.target.value)}
             />
           </div>
        </div>
      )})}
  </div>
 )
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI4wJ.png)